# Char to int8_t conversion gives unexpected results?

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion, byte, uint8t

Why casting `char` to `int8_t` keeps giving me the alphabetical (char) representation rather than numerical value?

Casting `char` to `int16_t` or `int` gives me expected numerical value.

```
char a = 'x';
std::cout << "Casting '" << a << "' (char) to (int8_t): " << (int8_t)a << '\n';
std::cout << "Casting '" << a << "' (char) to (int16_t): " << (int16_t)a << '\n';

unsigned char b = 'y';
std::cout << "Casting '" << b << "' (uchar) to (uint8_t): " << (uint8_t)b << '\n';
std::cout << "Casting '" << b << "' (uchar) to (uint16_t): " << (uint16_t)b << '\n';

// Further example:
int8_t c = 'z';
int16_t d = 'z';
int e = 'z';
std::cout << c << '\n' << d << '\n' << e << '\n';
```

Outputs:

```
Casting 'x' (char) to (int8_t): x
Casting 'x' (char) to (int16_t): 120
Casting 'y' (uchar) to (uint8_t): y
Casting 'y' (uchar) to (uint16_t): 121
z
122
122
```

My side goal is to read the file of characters into an array whose each each element is represented as `0..255` value (without any further casting).

My solution works fine:

```
auto buffer = std::make_unique<unsigned char[]>(file_length); // <uint8_t> also works
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer.get()), file_length);

for (int i = 0; i < file_length; i++) {
        std::cout << std::dec << (uint16_t)buffer[i] << std::endl;
}
```

However it still requires casting to `uint16_t` and interpreting as decimal, in order to print the result as a `0..255` number.

An alternative would be to simply use `uint16_t` as a type of an array, that way there would be no further casting other than interpreting as decimal, however I am still curious why `uint8_t` won't work.

Thanks.

Comment: It is unspecified whether `int8_t` is equivalent to any other type.   This means it is permitted to be an alias of `char`.   If you want the numeric value, I suggest converting/promoting it to `int16_t` or to `int` (both can represent all values a `int8_t` can).    Practically, when doing calculations, the compiler implicitly promotes to `int` anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optional type `int8_t` does not have to exist, but when it does, it's *very often* an alias for `char` (or `signed char`) and is therefor picked up by

`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, char);`

when you stream it, which, as you've noticed, outputs the character and not its numeric value.

So, to output an `int8_t`'s (or `char`'s) numeric value, you need to cast:

`std::cout << static_cast<int>(variable);`